# Safe Traversal Operations for Iterators

Tags: c++, c++14

**Motivation**

I have found on occasion that I have needed to safely increment/decrement iterators by ensuring they are within some bounded range.  After reading through some implementations (SO, Boost Summer code) and a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4317.pdf), I found that most of these "safe" functions did not handle the case where a negative difference type was used.  From the [C++ standard (C++14 Draft N4140 24.4.4)](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf):

> ```
> template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
> void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `n` shall be negative only for bidirectional and random access iterators.

If I am going to provide "safe" versions of the traversal operations `advance()`, `next()`, and `prev()`, I should *at least* meet those minimum requirements.

**Implementation**

```
#ifndef MY_ITERATOR_H
#define MY_ITERATOR_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace my {

template <typename Iterator, typename Distance>
auto safe_next(Iterator, Iterator, Iterator, Distance);

namespace details {

template <typename RandIt, typename Distance>
inline void safe_advance_helper(RandIt& curr, RandIt first, RandIt last,
                                Distance offset,
                                std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
  std::advance(curr, std::max(std::min(std::distance(curr, last), offset),
                              std::distance(first, curr)));
}

template <typename BidirIt, typename Distance>
inline void safe_advance_helper(BidirIt& curr, BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
                                Distance offset,
                                std::bidirectional_iterator_tag) {
  for (; 0 < offset && last != curr; --offset) {
    std::advance(curr, 1);
  }
  for (; offset && first != curr; ++offset) {
    std::advance(curr, -1);
  }
}

template <typename FwdIt, typename Distance>
inline void safe_advance_helper(FwdIt& curr, FwdIt first, FwdIt last,
                                Distance offset, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
  if (0 > offset) {
    const auto offset_from_first = std::distance(first, curr) + offset;
    curr = safe_next(first, first, last, std::max(0, offset_from_first));
  } else {
    for (; offset && curr != last; --offset) {
      std::advance(curr, 1);
    }
  }
}

template <typename InputIt, typename Distance>
inline void safe_advance_helper(InputIt& curr, InputIt first, InputIt last,
                                Distance offset, std::input_iterator_tag) {
  if (0 > offset) {
    throw std::out_of_range(
        "N4140 24.2.3 - Input iterators do no support increment or multipass "
        "dereferencing.");
  }
  for (; offset && curr != last; --offset) {
    std::advance(curr, 1)l
  }
}
} // namespace details

template <typename InputIt, typename Distance>
inline void safe_advance(InputIt& curr, InputIt first, InputIt last,
                         Distance offset) {
  details::safe_advance_helper(
      curr, first, last, offset,
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category());
}

template <typename InputIt, typename Distance>
inline auto safe_next(InputIt curr, InputIt first, InputIt last,
                      Distance offset) {
  safe_advance(curr, first, last, offset);
  return curr;
}

template <typename InputIt, typename Distance>
inline auto safe_prev(InputIt curr, InputIt first, InputIt last,
                      Distance offset) {
  safe_advance(curr, first, last, -offset);
  return curr;
}
} // namespace my

#endif
```

**Review**

1. Should I ensure that the advancing iterator starts within the range of (`first`, `last`)?
2. The forward iterator version of `safe_advance` advances from the start since it has that information.  Should I keep this or fall back to the input iterator behavior (throw on decrement)?
3. Some consider the need for both `first` and `last` to be tedious, which is why almost all "safe" versions only implement `last`.  Would it be better to split the decrement case from `advance()` into another function, say `prior()`, and move away from `std::ptrdiff_t` to `std::size_t`?
4. Anything else you'd like to comment on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you market yours as *safe*, yes, as long as it's not too costly, thus only for randomaccess-iterators by default. Remember though to treat it as an *error*.
   Provide a paranoid mode for forward iterators and bidirectional iterators to be checked as well, and disable those checks for release.

   That leads to companion-functions for checking whether the iterator is actually in the range, and additional ones for moving it to start resp. end of the range if not in there (supplied a bigger containing range) which returns whether a correction was neccessary.
2. You should not allow the algorithm take such an unanticipatedly larger time-span. Handle it just like any other programmer-error.

   A different algorithm advertizing that service might be a good idea though.
3. Consider to accept a *range* instead of two iterators. There's a reason people are working on getting those into the standard library.
4. You shouldn't throw on programmer-error, as that introduces the need for exception-handling where previously there was none, with unpredictable consequences and loss of performance.

   Instead, just go for `std::terminate()` directly.
5. The proposal you linked doesn't allow free choice of distance-type for *any* function. The standard only allows it for `advance`. Let's hope nobody passes an unsigned value to `safe_prev`...

---

- The random-iterator-case can be more elegantly and succinctly and clearly written with a `boost::clamp`:

  ```
  curr += boost::clamp(offset, first - curr, last - curr);
  ```
- I wonder why you call the base-function instead of going on with the task for the forward-iterator-case, after finding the start.
  Also, if you stay with it, invest in a `std::safe_distance`...

Comment: C++ makes use of a idiom called RAII, which in simple terms means objects should perform initialization in the constructor and cleanup in the destructor. For instance the std::ofstream class [may] open the file during the constructor, then the user performs output operations on it, and finally at the end of its life cycle, usually determined by its scope, the destructor is called that essentially closes the file and flushes any written content into the disk. `std::terminate` is as bad as `std::exit` to use.

Comment: @DrProgrammer: I'm not getting whatever point you have, sorry. Also, why don't you thing aborting the program is the right reaction to detecting internal corruption?  Do you have any better idea?